# Using C # LINQ to Select within 2 tags that has a descendant node equal to a certain value?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to select all objects within 2 tags specifically `<AR>`'s that contains an element that's a descendant of `<AR>: <RL>` with a certain value say 2. `<RL>` can be buried an arbitrary number of levels within `<AR>`'s, but will always be within `<AR>`. How can I do this in LINQ?

EX1:

```
<ARS>
  <AR> 
    <EI> </EI>
      <RL>5</RL>
  </AR>
  <AR> 
    <EI> </EI>
      <RL>2</RL>
  </AR>  
</ARS>
```

Result :

```
  <AR> 
        <EI> </EI>
          <RL>2</RL>
  </AR>
```

I tried using

```
IEnumerable<XNode> test_var = from result in doc.Descendants("AR")
                                                  where result.DescendantNodes()
```

But go from here, but this threw an error msg

Answer (score 1):

First problem is you need a `select` statement, such as adding `select result`.

Additionally your `where` needs to be a boolean. It sounds like you are looking for existence, which is frequently handled via the `Any()` extension method.

```
var searchString = "2";
IEnumerable<XElement> test_var = from result in doc.Descendants("AR")
                                 where result.Descendants("RL").Any(xelm => xelm.Value == searchString)
                                 select result;
```

Comment: What if I simply want value of <RL> to contain a certain string, disregarding case??

Comment: @jerryh91: If you want to replace "2", then you can replace the contents of `Any`. If you want to replace "RL" then you will need to remove "RL".

Comment: What I mean is that instead of checking if value of <RL>==2 like it is in your answer, I'd like to check if the value of <RL> contains a certain string

Comment: @jerryh91: I would highly recommend looking into how lambdas work. I have updated my answer to make it more obvious how to look for a certain string.

Comment: But I don't want ==, Simply Contains this string, disregarding case

Comment: @jerryh91: `xelm.Value == searchString` is the logic to check for equivalence, you can replace it with any bool, such as `xelm.Value.Contains(searchString)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var test_var = from result in doc.Descendants("AR")
               where result.Descendants("RL").Any(x => (int)x == 2)
               select result;
```

Comment: Is there an explicit conversion from `XElement` to `int`? Also pure code answers aren't ideal, especially when the poster doesn't recognize the "You are missing select" error.

Comment: @Guvante Yes, there is a conversion from `XElement` to `int` and a lot more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986933.aspx

Comment: What if I simply want value of <RL> to contain a certain string, disregarding case??